# ios coredata searching large datasets

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-data

I'm working on an enterprise ios application for the iphone that uses coredata as its persistence store.  We have a couple core data entities and one of them has 30~ fields.  My data set exceeds 45,000 of these 30-field entities.

I need to construct a query where my search string can match one of 12 different fields on the object.  My NSPredicate is basically a big rats nest of (property == $A) || (otherproperty == $A) ... etc where $A is my search string.

We're just starting to tune this for performance because it's pretty bad.  Are there any obvious things we should do?  Would it be better to use compound predicates and just have each sub-predicate be (property == $A) ?

Thoughts?  Thanks in advance.

My (partial) solution
- I watched some wwdc videos on core data and basically did what Apple said.  Which was to create a relationship from my real object to another object to represent a search-token.  This new search-token entity had two fields - token and weight.  When I insert my main object into coredata I give him a set of these search-tokens.  One search-token per field I want to query over and the contents of the token property are some sort of normalized (all lowercase) data.  Then my predicate is simply "ANY searchTokens.token beginswith %@".  So now we're just searching one table over its indexed field and we're not having to do any expersions in the right side of the where clause.  Coredata is really fast searching like this.  The only other thing I did was to put an NSTimer in shouldReloadTableForSearchString to only fire off the search after 1 second of inactivity.

[UISearchDisplayController - wait for N seconds OR for user to press "Search" before conducting search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347369/uisearchdisplaycontroller-wait-for-n-seconds-or-for-user-to-press-search-bef)

Comment: This is just my opinion, don't know if you can do it, but since I am doing iOS development, I get rid of all my web-application + relational-database background, and sometimes I found really helpful to do calculation about multi field value then store either in a non persistent or persistent attribute just to be used only for specific fetch request. Just remeber to refresh data during save and update of NSManagedObject.

Comment: Which video did you see this in, could you share that? Also, since you had multiple entities did you use a single searchToken object or more than one of these? Any problems connecting a single search token object to more than one entity? Thanks for making this answer so useful.

Answer (score 3):

Using compound predicates will give you the same result as a long string with `||`, so no, that won't help.

What might help is to optimize the order of the predicates. They're evaluated left to right, and evaluation stops as soon as the result is known. If you have a long chain of logical ORs, and the first one is true, it doesn't matter what the rest of them look like. Those predicates won't even be evaluated.

So, if you can reasonably expect that some properties are more likely to match than others, move those to the front of the list. If one will be YES almost all of the time, make that the first one.

Also, if any of these predicates are numeric, move those toward the front of the line. Numeric comparisons are much faster than string comparison, so any numeric check that returns YES will let you skip any following string comparisons.

Comment: Also on the NSFetchRequest you can specify fetch limit and or batch size

Comment: Yes - the batch size really helped a lot!  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Tom!  I figured that is what coredata was doing under the covers but I wasn't sure..